# Open 1 different activity for each cardview

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm trying to figure how to go to another activity when I click on one item of a `cardview` (with `recyclerview`).
I searched on internet and this website and tried several options, but it isn't working (I tried only for position 0, the others will be done the same). Here, with the card 0 i try to go to "selection_niveau".

1st try : inside OnClick:

```
public class adapter_categorie_solo extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter_categorie_solo.ViewHolder> {

    List<String> titles;
    List<Integer> images;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public adapter_categorie_solo(Context ctx, List<String> titles, List<Integer> images){
        this.titles = titles;
        this.images = images;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_solo_categorie,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(titles.get(position));
        holder.gridIcon.setImageResource(images.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titles.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView title;
        ImageView gridIcon;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            gridIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked -> " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (getAdapterPosition()==0)
                    Intent intent = new Intent (this,selection_niveau.class);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error :

```
error: variable declaration not allowed here
                    Intent intent = new Intent (this,selection_niveau.class);
```

2nd try : inside onBindViewHolder

```
public class adapter_categorie_solo extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter_categorie_solo.ViewHolder> {

    List<String> titles;
    List<Integer> images;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public adapter_categorie_solo(Context ctx, List<String> titles, List<Integer> images){
        this.titles = titles;
        this.images = images;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_solo_categorie,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(titles.get(position));
        holder.gridIcon.setImageResource(images.get(position));
        Intent intent;
        if(position == 0)
            intent = new Intent(this, selection_niveau.class);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override public void onClick(View v){
                Context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titles.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView title;
        ImageView gridIcon;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            gridIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked -> " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this error :

```
error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(adapter_categorie_solo,Class<selection_niveau>)
            intent = new Intent(this, selection_niveau.class);
                     ^
    constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; adapter_categorie_solo cannot be converted to String)
    constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; adapter_categorie_solo cannot be converted to Context)
```

I tried to change "this" to only "context", but it doesn't work either.

These are some of the solutions I found on internet and here, but none is working and I can't really understand why as being a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Intent` constructor requires a context as the first argument, but `this` in the ViewHolder refers to the instance of `ViewHolder`, So you need to get context from the view or use the context reference you got in the constructor of the `adapter_categorie_solo`.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView title;
        ImageView gridIcon;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            gridIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked -> " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (getAdapterPosition()==0)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent (ctx,selection_niveau.class);
                        ctx.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Using `switch` instead of `if` will be an optimal approach if you want to start different activity based on click position.

Comment: It's partially working ! It open a new activity, but shut it down directly. However, the new activity is for now not complicated, just an imageview, so I don't really see what is going wrong ...

Comment: what is being shutdown?

Comment: The new activity. I click on the first card (number 0), it opens the new activity, which shut down immediately, and i'm redirected to my main activity.

Comment: please check your Log, there is a crash in the new activity after the crash app is starting again.

Comment: Trying to restart it to check the log, but now I have another error that I didn't have before, don't understand why                                                                                
 error: cannot find symbol
          ctx.startActivity(in);                                                                                                   symbol: variable in

Comment: It doesn't recognize the "in" anymore.                                                                           `error: cannot find symbol
                        ctx.startActivity(in);
                                                ^
  symbol: variable in`

Comment: typo err, fixed it

Comment: Everything is now working perfectly, the new activity is now running perfectly! Don't really know why it was shutting down before tho. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `onClick()` callback `this` keyword will points to the anonymous inner class of the `View.OnClickListener`; so you need to change to a context by using `v.getContext()` instead.

Apply this by replacing `itemView.setOnClickListener` with:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked -> " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (getAdapterPosition()==0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), selection_niveau.class);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thx for your help, but I get this error (that i already had before ) :                                     
 error: variable declaration not allowed here
                        Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), selection_niveau.class);

Comment: @HugoBecker .. you need to wrap it in curly braces { } .. `if` without curly braces doesn't allow to define items in it .. please see updated answer .. by the way this will run only for the first row item click .. You can remove the `if` condition to run it for all row items

Comment: No error now, but it's not opening the activity... By the way, using other "if" for other items, like 1,2.... and therefore open another activity will work too ?

Comment: @HugoBecker can you remove this condition, and test

Comment: I removed the condition, it's the same : no error but it's not opening the new activity

Comment: Is the Toast `Clicked -> ` shown on the screen?

Comment: Please show the code of `selection_niveau.class`

Comment: `import android.os.Bundle;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class selection_niveau extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selection_niveau);

    }
}`

Comment: Have you added `selection_niveau` to the `manifest` file ?

Comment: I did. `<activity android:name=".selection_niveau" />`

Comment: @HugoBecker the code you provided so far should work ... can you consider creating a demo project in github in order to allow us reproduce the issue ..

Comment: I rebooted Android Studio and updated all the files (sdk...) and now it works ! Don't know why it didn't worked before... Thanks a lot for your time. I understood where was my error at the beginning. Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

use `context` in `Intent` instead of `this`

```
if(position == 0)
     intent = new Intent(context, selection_niveau.class);
```

Comment: I already tried to use context, but it says this is an unknown variable....